# Query youtube music channel with youtube Analytics API

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics

I'm trying to retrieve data from Youtube Analytics API with this query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&metrics=views&filters=country==US&start-date=2015-05-13&end-date=2015-05-14&access_token={mytoken}
```

`UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ` is youtube's music channel Id but I'm getting a Forbidden error.

Is there a way I can query music statics by country and worldwide?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I recently found out I can only use Youtube Analytics API to get data from Channels I own.